# How do you deal with NULL values in columns of type boolean in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, null, odbc, boolean

I was wondering if there is a better way to cope with MS-Access' inability to handle NULL for boolean-values other than change the column-data-type to integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use a number, and so, it seems does [Allen Browne, Access MVP](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html).

Comment: Thanks Remou, there are some good tips on Allen Browne's site :)

Comment: If you enjoy Allen Browne, you may also like Tony Toews. He is particularly good on corruption: http://www.granite.ab.ca/accsmstr.htm

Comment: @RobertHarvey it was not completely necessary, I have added a link to Allen Browne's tip page and removed the forum link.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've found :(  I haven't programmed Access in awhile, but what I remember involves quite a lot of isNull checks.

Comment: Yes, Access can handle Null values for other data types, but when I link a table from a DB with boolean-types, Access treats Null like False.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you want your app/solution to *interpret* said NULLs in your data.
Do you want to simply "ignore" them in a report... i.e. have them print out as blank spaces or newlines?  In that case you can use the handy IsNull function along with the "immediate if" iif() in either the SQL builder or a column in the regular Access query designer as follows:
IIF(IsNull(*BooleanColumnName*), *NewLine/BlankSpace/Whatever*, *BooleanColumnName*)
On the other hand, if you want to consider the NULLs as "False" values, you had better update the column and just change them with something like:
Update *table* 
SET *BooleanColumnName* = FALSE 
WHERE *BooleanColumnName* IS NULL